# Display SQL Query Result using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, this

I have a news feed on my site, onto which users can post posts. These posts can then be liked by other users (just like facebook for example).

---

**The Problem**
I would like to display the users, who liked a post using ajax. Whenever a certain element is hovered.
**At the moment the users are correctly displayed but below every post, not just the one which contains the hovered element.**

---

**My attempt to solve the problem**

```
<!-- HOVER THIS -->
<span class="likers small link"></span>

<!-- DISPLAY LIKERS HERE -->
<small class="displayLikers"></small>

<!-- AJAX -->
<script>
    $(function() {
        $(".likers").hover(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "get/likers",
                type: "GET",
                success: function(response) {
                    $(this).closest('.displayLikers').html(response);
                }
           });
        });
    });
</script>
```

---

I would be very thankful for any kind of help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `$.ajax`, `$(this)` does not refer to `$(".likers")` just add `$(this)` to a variable and use it in the ajax response function;

```
$(function() {
    $(".likers").hover(function(){
        var likes = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: "get/likers",
            type: "GET",
            success: function(response) {
                likes.closest('.displayLikers').html(response);
            }
       });
    });
});
```

Comment: Great! Thank you! I will accept the answer, as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

In your example the `.displayLikers` is a sibling so you should probably use `next()`. Moreover `this` will refer to the actual context of the success function, so you have to create a reference before.

```
$(function() {
    $(".likers").hover(function(){
        var self = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: "get/likers",
            type: "GET",
            success: function(response) {
                self.next('.displayLikers').html(response);
            }
       });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Ashkan Mobayen Khiabani was a little faster than you, therefore I accepted his correct answer.